# Enum having multiple attributes as a Collection Constant

Tags: python, enums

In a recent question ([Gathering numerical data from a string input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452970/gathering-numerical-data-from-a-string-input)) I was wondering whether this was an acceptable answer. I thought that it would make a better question. Is this kind of representation acceptable as a constant collection? Or is it a misuse of enums? And are there any unexpected consequences from assigning the same value to the different attributes on the enum in Python?

```
from enum import Enum
class CreditRating(Enum):
     AAA = 0.01
     A = 0.1
     B = 0.1
creditRate = input("Please enter credit rating:")
print(CreditRating[creditRate].value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums are *associations between unique names and unique values*. Using a value more than once is supported, but may not be what you intended it to mean. This is explicitly covered in the documentation, see the [*Duplicating enum members and values* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#duplicating-enum-members-and-values):

> [T]wo enum members are allowed to have the same value. Given two members A and B with the same value (and A defined first), B is an alias to A.

The consequence is that looking up a name by value, will only return the first name:

```
>>> CreditRating(0.1)
<CreditRating.A: 0.1>
```

and when you look at `B`, you'll be given the `A` enum object:

```
>>> CreditRating.B
<CreditRating.A: 0.1>
```

If all you wanted to do was map a string to a value, I'd not use an enum, just use a dictionary:

```
credit_ratings = {
    'AAA': 0.01, 
    'A': 0.1,
    'B': 0.1,
}
# ...
print(credit_ratings[creditRate])
```

Use an `enum` when you need the other features such a definition provides, such as the explicit aliasing, the fact that enum values are singletons (you can use `is` to test for them) and that you can map both names and values back to enum objects.

Comment: I often want to use `Enum` with `pydantic` to define a `str` choice for JSON and then use the enum **values** within the app. In this case providing `'{"credit_rating":"AAA"}'` and let Pydantic convert that to `assert input.credit_rating.value == 0.01`. But it seems Python and Pydantic conspire together so that after several `Enum` improvements over different versions of Python and now Pydantic 2 but I still can't do this out of the box I have to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75587442/validate-pydantic-dynamic-float-enum-by-name-with-openapi-description Surely a common use case.